# intl ICU version installed on your system (64.1) does not match the ICU data bundled with Symfony (57.1)"

Tags: orocrm

While Runing the orocrm services for system check information in my localhost this types of error is occurred "intl ICU version installed on your system (64.1) does not match the ICU data bundled with Symfony (57.1)"

This is for a new Linux server, running MySQL 5, PHP 5 and Apache 2. In the past, I’ve tried on existing servers and always seem to end up having to fall back to ISO-8859-1.”

intl ICU version installed on your system (64.1) does not match the ICU data bundled with Symfony (57.1)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as PHP 5 is not supported anymore, you should switch to PHP 7.1 or 7.2.

Also, make sure you are installing the latest available LTS version of OroCRM as it has no known issues with ICU library shipped with popular Linux distributions.

For more details on installation see the documentation https://oroinc.com/orocrm/doc/current/install-upgrade/installation-quick-start-dev/crm